# HttpException on Sitecore logs

Tags: sitecore-client, logging

I have been working with Sitecore version 8.2, with three to four sites in one instance. Everything work fine, but in logs the following errors are seen.

```
 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web.WebPages
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Just wondering how this error occurs on the site and none of the functionality is affected. Please provide an detailed explanation regarding the same

Comment: We use not Sitecore but ASP.NET WebPages.
We find that the same error occurs about every 21 minutes in our environment, though we don't know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

> about every 21 minutes

The application pool in our environment was

- General/Start Mode=AlwaysRunning
- Process Model/Idle Time-out(minutes)=20

We had changed the time-out to 1, now the error occurs about every 2 minutes.

---

We logged "Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath" when the error occurred.

We found the wrong setting in our environment.
(web.config / configuration / system.webServer / applicationInitialization)

Correct)`<add initializationPage="foo/bar.cshtml" />`

Wrong)`<add initializationPage="~/foo/bar.cshtml" />`

The wrong setting caused the wrong path.
(~/~/foo/bar.cshtml)

The correct setting resolved the error in our environment.

Comment: Will check this and let you know the results